# How get value of field from another entity (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to get value of field from another entity. I have next models:

```
@Entity
public class ProductOwnerFields {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String customValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "templateField_id")
    private TemplateFields templateFields;

    private int order;
    //gettees and setters
}

@Entity
public class TemplateFields{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "order_field")
    private int order = 0;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    //gettees and setters
}
```

How can I get value of field "ORDER" of the TemplateFields and set to field "ORDER" of ProductOwnerFields? I need only anotations JPA or Hibernate, use EntityManager.

In total I need to make EntityManager.find(ProductOwnerFields .class, id) and get object of ProductOwnerFields with "order" value from "order" of TemplateFields.

Comment: If they are the same value why you need them in both entities?

Comment: "Order" from ProductOwnerFields will not be stored in the database. In the future, I will use @OrderBy "order" of ProductOwnerFields level up for sorting

Comment: what about calling  order TemplateFields  getter in order ProductOwnerFields setter !

Comment: order of ProductOwnerFields isn't saved in database, it will look like this @Transient private int order;

Answer (score 1):

Can try this:

```
@Entity
public class ProductOwnerFields {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String customValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "templateField_id")
    private TemplateFields templateFields;

    private int order;

    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad() {
        if(templateFields != null) {
            this.order = templateFields.getOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

This can answer your question but is not recommended.
In JPA, you can build a CriteriaQuery and directly inject search criteria "order" field of "templateFields" of ProductOwnerFields type. No need to have a "order" field in ProductOwnerFields.

You can look over this to know how to use CriteriaQuery : https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 1):

when you uses eager, it Consists of loading an entity or a collection as soon as possible,
Irrespective of whether the application subsequently uses them or not.

Then  you can get the code using :

```
productField.getTemplateFields().getOrder()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
@Entity
public class ProductOwnerFields {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String customValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "templateField_id")
    private TemplateFields templateFields;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private TemplateFields templateFields;
}

@Entity
public class TemplateFields{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "order_field")
    private int order = 0;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: In Java you cannot have 2 fields in the same class with the same name! Compiler error